# Knockout Multiple Actions On Binding Pass Self

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code:

```
<button data-bind="click:function(){ saveTask(), toggle()}">Save</button>
```

My saveTask function is as follows:

```
self.saveTask = function(item){
    alert(JSON.stringify(item));
}
```

I am getting an error that item is not defined.

Normally when I have one function bound to my click it would just be:

```
<button data-bind="click:saveTask">Save</button>
```

Then the item I am currently on would be passed to the saveTask function, when I am binding multiple functions on a click how would I pass the current item ( self ) to the saveTask function?

Comment: You need to have `item` as an argument to your anonymous function and then you need to pass it on to `saveTask`.

Comment: Don't define complex inline binding handlers. Just. don't. (Complex means: Anything involving the `function` keyword). Make a viewmodel function that carries out complex functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't passing arguments to your bound function or to the functions that it calls. Your binding ought to look like:

`<button data-bind="click: function(item){ saveTask(item); toggle(item); }">Save</button>`

When you write `data-bind="click: saveTask"`, Knockout is calling `saveTask` like this under the hood: `saveTask(item)`. Since you're instead providing it with an anonymous function, you need to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "**function**" keyword in **data-bind** attribute is very "*unsexy*"!

However, if you like it you can do it like this:

```
<button data-bind="click:function(){ saveTask($data), toggle($data)}">Save</button>
```

In my opinion you should create a function in your viewModel:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
  var vmA = {
    action: saveTaskAndToogle,
    label: 'Sexy Save'
  };
  
  var vmB = {
    saveTask:saveTask,
    toggle:toggle,
    label: 'Unsexy save'
  };
  
  ko.applyBindings(vmA, window.a);
  ko.applyBindings(vmB, window.b);

  function saveTask(k,ev){ alert("save: "   + k.label); }
  function toggle(k, ev) { alert("toggle: " + k.label); }
  
  function saveTaskAndToogle(/*koData, event*/){
     saveTask.apply(this, arguments);
     toggle  .apply(this, arguments);
    }
});
```

```html
<button id="a"  
        data-bind="click: action,
                   text: label"></button>
<button id="b" 
        data-bind="click: function(){ saveTask($data), toggle($data)},
                   text:label"></button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

> By default knockout will inject $data (self) and event.

If you require any further information, let me know.